# Custom Widget function in Plugin not working?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I took a code straight out of one of my themes I created, and it's a list of all 50 states in an unordered list packed into a widget you can just drag and drop on the sidebar.

The problem is, when I try using this code in a PLUGIN file, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 431`

Why would it work in the theme, but not in the plugin? By the way, the active theme is NOT the theme I took the code out of.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/ZeRWW3yb

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try replacing :

```
register_widget('States_Widget');
```

with:

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'register_states_widget');
function register_states_widget() {
    register_widget('States_Widget');
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: One-liner: add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("States_Widget");'));

Comment: Those one-liners have the severe disadvantage that if users want to issue remove_action, they can't, because there is no hooked function that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that you need to initialize a widget inside a class method by passing the widget name as an argument. To accomplish this you would do this:

```
class WidgetMonster {
    /**
     * Register widget via PHP lambda function as an argument to the add_action function
     * @var $widget_name string | WP_Widget.
     */
    public static function register_widget_helper( $widget_name ) {
        add_action('widgets_init',
            function() use ( &$widget_name ) {
                return register_widget( $widget_name );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Note that we need to pass the variable `$widget_name` name to our lambda function in order to use it. The part doing this is `use (&$widget_name)`. As already noted hooks initialized like this cannot be removed by `remove_action`.